# Rename files in linux with regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, rename

This is not actually a question, I solved this myself. But I wanted to post my solution here to save other people in the same situation time and effort.

So I came into the situation where I had to rename a lot (+3000) matching a certain pattern. In my case, the files were automatic backups from syncthing, so a file would be renamed like this:

```
foo.bar -> foo~20150221-1330.bar
```

Comment: If you've got a question with an answer, please put the question in the question field and then add an answer with your answer.  That way it's clearer what's going on, and it's easier for other people to add their answers too :).

Comment: Note that you can still post an answer here, and reword this post to shape it into a question.

Comment: Where is the answer? And also, I can't really see what the question is. Something about renaming lots of files? *"matching a certain pattern"* What's the pattern?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I was editing my post, sorry ;) Now I have a question and answer + a little dissection of the command I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching trough forums and man pages, I created the following one-liner which restores the original filename with the find, `sed`, `xargs` and `mv` commands in linux:

```
find . -type f  | sed -e 'p;s/\(.*\)~20[0-9]\{6\}-[0-9]\{6\}\(.*\)/\1\2/' | xargs -n2 -d'\n' mv
```

If you can replace the `sed`-part with your own pattern if you like. This command can handle whitespaces by the way (thanks to the `-d'\n'` flag in `xargs`), but not newlines.
I hope some of you find this command useful.

Ok so I'll give some more information about what each command does:

- `find`: give all regular files (not directories) in the current directory
- `sed`: `p` will print every line from stdin, the `s/regex/regex/` will print the same lines, but substituted. So you get each file followed by the fixed filename:

  ```
  ./foo/bar~20150221-172703.txt
  ./foo/bar.txt`
  ```
- `xargs`: `-n2` will take two lines and send them to `mv` as parameter, -d'\n' will fix issues with whitespaces in folder names (the delimiter is set to newline instead of whitespace)

Comment: You'll get an error like `mv: ‘stuff’ and ‘stuff’ are the same file` when the file doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: Sorry for the bad layout, I'm new to stackoverflow...
@gniourf_gniourf yes, if you dont like errors you can append `2> /dev/null` , but it won't do anything with the files who don't match.

Comment: There's another problem in your method: what if there's a file like `dir~20150221-172703/file`? you'll get an error too.

Comment: In my case, the directories won't have other names (synthing doesn't rename the directories). But if you have a solution for that I would like to see it, I'm always wanting to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is good, but if you also want to address filenames that also contain newlines, if you don't want to use `sed` and if you want to make sure that only files with *basename* that matches this pattern are taken into account (your method fails, e.g., with `dir~20150221-172703/file`, and your method makes `mv` complain a lot about `file` and `file` being the same file when the filename doesn't match your pattern) you need to proceed slightly differently.

---

One possibility, if your `find` supports the `-print0` option (GNU `find` does): have `find` spit all the filenames, and use a `while` loop in which Bash (not `sed`) will perform the substitution. Something like this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    dirname=${file%/*}
    basename=${file##*/}
    # Perform the substitution only on basename
    # Since you like regex, you can use them
    if [[ $basename =~ ^(.*)~20[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}(.*)$ ]]; then
        new_basename=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        echo mv "$dirname/$basename" "$dirname/$new_basename"
    fi
done
```

You could also make sure `find` only spits matching files by using the `-regex` filter (not POSIX, but GNU `find` supports it):

```
find . -regextype posix-basic -regex '.*~20[0-9]\{6\}-[0-9]\{6\}[^/]*' -type f
```

Not sure this fully answers your question, but at least it fixes the flaws your method has.

Without GNU goodies, it's more difficult to have something robust and clean...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm):

```
rnm -rs '/(.*)~20[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{6}(.*)/\1\2/' -fo -dp -1 *
```

1. `-fo` : file only mode
2. `-dp` : depth of directory (-1 means unlimited depth i.e goes to all sub-directories).

You could use your own regex pattern exactly though, in that case you would have to change the regex mode to basic (BRE):

```
rnm --regex basic -rs '/\(.*\)~20[0-9]\{6\}-[0-9]\{6\}\(.*\)/\1\2/' -fo -dp -1 *
```

**Note:**

1. Only invalid characters are the null character and the path delimiter (`/`).
2. Default regex mode is javascript.